# Replace operators of equation, so that the sum is equal to zero

Tags: algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming, backtracking

I'm given the equation like this one:

```
n = 7
1 + 1 - 4 - 4 - 4 - 2 - 2
```

How can I optimally replace operators, so that the sum of the equation is equal to zero, or print  `-1`. I think of one algorithm, but it is not optimal. I have an idea to bruteforce all cases with complexity `O(n*2^n)`, but `(n < 300)`.

Here is the link of the problem: http://codeforces.com/gym/100989/problem/M.

Comment: One way to prune the search tree in case of backtracking could be to realize that `+ 4 - 4` is the same as `- 4 + 4`.

Comment: Grab total parity, if it's odd print -1.

Comment: No, numbers are `1 <= x < 300`

Comment: @Vesper what about minimum number of replacements?

Comment: This looks like balancing two piles of numbers, certainly there's an algorithm of solving that one. I also wonder if you can add a minus sign before the first number to count as one replacement.

Comment: @Vesper No you can't.

Comment: Then check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem and the presented dynamic programming solution. Probably correctly implementing this one with predefined subsets will provide you the answer.

Comment: @Vesper I thought about it too, but `Partition problem` can only answer if we can divide sequence, but can't optimally choose what to replace.

Comment: Okay then, it's not directly a partitioning problem, but a subset sum problem, these two are related. The main difference here as I see it, is first that you need to query all possible subsets for the same sum, and choose the one that has the least differences from the original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the implementation in C++:

```
unordered_map <int, int> M, U;
unordered_map<int, int>::iterator it;
int a[] = {1, -1, 4, -4};

int solve() {
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        if(i == 0) M[a[i]] = 1;
        else {
            vector <pair <int, int>> vi;
            for(it = M.begin(); it != M.end(); ++it) {
                int k = it->first, d = it->second;
                vi.push_back({k + a[i], d});
                vi.push_back({k - a[i], d + 1});
            }
            for(int j = 0; j < vi.size(); ++j) M[vi[j].first] = MAXN;
            for(int j = 0; j < vi.size(); ++j) {
                M[vi[j].first] = min(M[vi[j].first], vi[j].second);
            }
        }
    }
    return (M[0] == 0 ? -1 : M[0] - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can solve this with dynamic programming. Keep a map of all possible partial sums (mapping to the minimum number of changes to reach this sum), and then update it one number at a time,

Here's a concise Python solution:

```
def signs(nums):
    xs = {nums[0]: 0}
    for num in nums[1:]:
        ys = dict()
        for d, k in xs.iteritems():
            for cost, n in enumerate([num, -num]):
                ys[d+n] = min(ys.get(d+n, 1e100), k+cost)
        xs = ys
    return xs.get(0, -1)

print signs([1, 1, -4, -4, -4, -2, -2])
```

In theory this has exponential complexity in the worst case (since the number of partial sums can double at each step). However, if (as here) the given numbers are always (bounded) small ints, then the number of partial sums grows linearly, and the program works in O(n^2) time.

A somewhat more optimised version uses a sorted array of (subtotal, cost) instead of a dict. One can discard partial sums that are too large or too small (making it impossible to end up at 0 assuming all of the remaining elements are between -300 and +300). This runs approximately twice as fast, and is a more natural implementation to port to a lower-level language than Python for maximum speed.

```
def merge(xs, num):
    i = j = 0
    ci = 0 if num >= 0 else 1
    cj = 0 if num < 0 else 1
    num = abs(num)
    while j < len(xs):
        if xs[i][0] + num < xs[j][0] - num:
            yield (xs[i][0] + num, xs[i][1] + ci)
            i += 1
        elif xs[i][0] + num > xs[j][0] - num:
            yield  (xs[j][0] - num, xs[j][1] + cj)
            j += 1
        else:
            yield (xs[i][0] + num, min(xs[i][1] + ci, xs[j][1] + cj))
            i += 1
            j += 1
    while i < len(xs):
        yield (xs[i][0] + num, xs[i][1] + ci)
        i += 1

def signs2(nums):
    xs = [(nums[0], 0)]
    for i in xrange(1, len(nums)):
        limit = (len(nums) - 1 - i) * 300
        xs = [x for x in merge(xs, nums[i]) if -limit <= x[0] <= limit]
    for x, c in xs:
        if x == 0: return c
    return -1

print signs2([1, 1, -4, -4, -4, -2, -2])
```

Comment: The cost should increase by 1 with each swap, I don't read the 1 here in `cost`.

Comment: @Vesper I admit the code is a little tricksy, but cost=0 for num and cost=1 for -num.

Comment: Impressive. And with numbers below 300, the size of `ys` will never exceed 180000, thus it's doable. The total complexity is worst case 180000*n, so I think this should be optimized with pre-checks like "if sum of numbers is odd, return -1" and "if `d+n` exceeds `sum/2` by module, don't add to `ys`".

Answer (score 0):

What I can think of:

You calculate the original equation. This results in -14.
Now you sort the numbers (taking into account their + or -)
When the equation results in a negative number, you look for the largest numbers to fix the equation. When a number is too large, you skip it.

orig_eq = -14

After sorting:

-4, -4, -4, -2, -2, 1, 1

You loop over this and select each number if the equation orig_eq - current number is closer to zero.

This way you can select each number to change the sign of

Comment: What is the complexity?

Comment: How does this algorithm work for "5-4-3+3-3"? The sum is -2, but you can't change a single number to make it closer to 0. But 5+4-3-3-3 is 0.

Comment: The partition problem is NP complete, so it's very unlikely that there's a guaranteed polynomial-time solution.

Comment: Very true, I had not thought about it that way.